# Issue selecting Category and SubCategory of an Item while creating one delimited string per row of a table

Tags: sql, oracle, join, inner-join, outer-join

Some Context: The DB is Oracle. I am trying to create one delimited string per row of a table. The delimited string needs to contain two of the item's categories (if available, there will always be one category at a minimum). There are 3 tables, ITEM, ITEM_CAT and ITEM_ITEM_CAT. The ITEM table holds all the items. The ITEM_CAT table holds all the possible item categories. The ITEM_ITEM_CAT holds all the mappings between the item IDs and the category IDs, a key value table essentially.

I have created the below SQL which is able to get the delimited string for a specific item, but I need a query which can run against the entire table.

```
SELECT 'ITEM'||'%#'|| outerTable.ITEM_ID ||'%#'|| 
    (SELECT midTable.item_cat_nam
     FROM
            (SELECT innerTable.item_cat_nam AS item_cat_nam, innerTable.item_id AS item_id, ROWNUM AS rn
             FROM
                    (SELECT ic.ITEM_CAT_NAM AS item_cat_nam, i.ITEM_ID AS item_id
                     FROM ITEM_CAT ic, ITEM_ITEM_CAT iic, ITEM i
                     WHERE i.ITEM_ID = iic.ITEM_ID 
                     AND iic.ITEM_CAT_CD = ic.ITEM_CAT_CD
                     AND 287484 = i.item_id
                    ) innerTable
            ) midTable
    WHERE rn = 1
    ) ||'%#'||
    (SELECT midTable.item_cat_nam
     FROM
            (SELECT innerTable.item_cat_nam AS item_cat_nam, innerTable.item_id AS item_id, ROWNUM AS rn
             FROM
                    (SELECT ic.ITEM_CAT_NAM AS item_cat_nam, i.ITEM_ID AS item_id
                     FROM ITEM_CAT ic, ITEM_ITEM_CAT iic, ITEM i
                     WHERE i.ITEM_ID = iic.ITEM_ID 
                     AND iic.ITEM_CAT_CD = ic.ITEM_CAT_CD
                     AND 287484 = i.item_id
                    ) innerTable
            ) midTable
    WHERE rn = 2
    )
FROM OFR outerTable
WHERE outerTable.ITEM_ID = 287484;
```

I need to be able to pass the outer table's ITEM_ID down into the last inner join. I could do this when I only need the category (via the below SQL statement, only one inner join needed), but with the introduction of multiple categories; I need rownum (to get multiple categories) which then needs more inner joins and I can't seem to pass the ITEM_ID down more than one inner join, and here lies the problem...

```
SELECT 'ITEM'||'%#'|| outerTable.OFR_ID ||'%#'|| 
    (SELECT ic.ITEM_CAT_NAM
     FROM ITEM_CAT ic, ITEM_ITEM_CAT iic, ITEM i
     WHERE i.ITEM_ID = iic.ITEM_ID 
     AND iic.ITEM_CAT_CD = ic.ITEM_CAT_CD
     AND outerTable.OFR_ID = i.item_id
             AND rownum = 1
    ) innerTable
FROM OFR outerTable;
```

Can anyone help with this?

Thank you in advance for any assitance.

Comment: From your example it looks like the Category is taken from the _first_ row returned from the innermost query (`SELECT ic.ITEM_CAT_NAM AS item_cat_nam, i.ITEM_ID AS item_id ...`) and the SubCategory is taken from the _second_ row returned (you repeat the query but this time filter for rn=2). Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, in my application, I have the concept of 'categories' only which an item can have many of. And a category can have many Items. The application I many integrating with is able to accept a category and subcategory only via the delimited string I am creating. In our instance the subcategory is jus another one of our categories if available. It is not a "'sub'category" of the given "category". The term is a bit misleading in this instance, apologies for that. I will edit original post. Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No worries. You need something like this...

```
SELECT 'ITEM' || '%#' || Item_ID || '%#' || CatName1 || '%#' || CatName2
FROM outerTable
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    Item_ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN Item_Cat_Nam ELSE NULL END) CatName1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN Item_Cat_Nam ELSE NULL END) CatName2
  FROM (
    SELECT
      Item_ID,
      Item_Cat.Item_Cat_Nam,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Item_ID ORDER BY Item_ID) rn
    FROM Item
    INNER JOIN Item_Item_Cat USING (Item_ID)
    INNER JOIN Item_Cat USING (Item_Cat_Cd)
  ) GROUP BY Item_ID
) USING (Item_ID)
```

The innermost query uses the ROW_NUMBER function to assign 1, 2, 3, etc. to every category found for each item. The PARTITION BY restarts the numbering at 1 for each item. The ORDER BY is required so I used Item_ID because hey, why not? If you have a preferred column to order by just use that - it will be used to assign the row numbers. The inner query will output something like this:

```
Item_ID  Item_Cat_Nam  rn
-------  ------------  --
      1  Category aa    1
      1  Category xy    2
      1  Category ef    3
      2  Category xy    1
      2  Category ax    2
      3  Category ef    1
```

The query surrounding the innermost query uses MAX to flatten the first two `rn` values for each Item_ID into a single row. The Item_Cat_Nam for rn=1 goes to the CatName1 column and the Item_Cat_Nam for rn=2 goes to the CatName2 column. When it's fed the results shown above you'll end up with this:

```
Item_ID  CatName1     CatName2
-------  -----------  -----------
      1  Category aa  Category xy  (note Category ef is rn=3 so it's ignored)
      2  Category xy  Category ax
      3  Category ef               (note only one row for Item_ID 3)
```

Then the very outer query just concatenates everything.

One other thing: I used the "JOIN ... USING" syntax because in this case it lets you eliminate all of the aliases (innerTable, i, ic, iic, midTable, etc.). That's purely because I'm more comfortable with it so it helped me figure this out a lot quicker. You should feel free to use your own join style - after all you'll be the one stuck maintaining it :)

Comment: Took me a while to figure out what you were doing with the MAX and the CASE in the middle SELECT - very smart.